# Relating multiple columns in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to create a table in mysql as:

```
create table interest(Lend float,
                      year int,
                      rate float,
                      interest_accumulated float);
```

Now, here in the above table I need to fill up the lend amount (principle), and time (year) and rate of interest and I need to get interest accumulated automatically filled up using the formula

```
I = lend(multiplied)year(multiplied)rate/100
```

without typing in the value to the table.

Also I need to protect the integrity by not allowing manual entry to the `interest_accumulated` column. And I want the `interest_accumulated` column to be in the same table ie "tablename" interest.

Is it possible to define such a format in mysql version 5.6.30-1(debian) system?

Comment: If the question is "can I have some kind of formula column", AFAIK the answer is No

Comment: what do you mean by formula column?

Comment: Not as far as I know. All of this is business logic that you'd have to implement using stored procedures or perhaps an accompanying application in another language (such as PHP)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a virtual/generated column.
You can read about details [here](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/). 
Edit:
However it's not available in mysql 5.6. If upgrade is not an option, you can have a 'before insert' trigger, that would calculate the value on insert. Guess 'before update' would be needed to avoid manual changes.